# Fetching the value from online database and list in Listview in android using notify changed

Tags: android

Hi Please anyone help in fetching the value from the online database using php and show in the listview by using notifychanged

Answer (score 0):

You should make a http connection to the php server and obtain the content as json or xml and parse it using JsonArray or xmlpullparser and then push the items into list view by calling the setAdapter method in your listView . Although you could customize your listView by creating a adapter instanceof BaseAdapter

Comment: if I use Like that the scroll view position is getting changed. Because I am trying to access the data from server for every few seconds

Comment: You can create a new Thread and specify a interval to connect to server and update the contents . But for you . I guess you had better create a webview and design a web page for your work and create a javascript interface to communicate between your web page and android app

Comment: ya I can but some one can un-zip my APK file and they can see the web page in assert folder so that there is chance of knowing my server details :(

Comment: No no you will load the page from the internet by using WebViewObject.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");